# redirect from node js server to nginx

Tags: node.js, redirect, express, nginx

I am trying to setup an nginx server in front of my nodejs server(with express).

This is my server config for nginx :

```
server {
  listen       8080;
  server_name  localhost:8080;
  root /usr/share/nginx/appHtml;
  autoindex on;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  }
}
```

My node server verifies the user and redirects the request to http://localhost:3000/u/user. Something like :

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    //verify user
    res.redirect('/u/user'); 
})
```

I want my window location to read **localhost:8080/u/user** instead of just **localhost:8080** after this redirect as is the case when i am running my nodejs server without nginx.

Similarly i want the same behaviour for all my server redirects.

How do i achieve this?

Comment: just to clarify: you're saying that if you redirect via nodejs, the url in the browser does not change to the url you're redirecting to?

Comment: @mvuajua : yes that's precisely my problem.

Comment: Try adding `proxy_set_header Host $host;` to your nginx location block

Comment: @mvuajua : That did not help. Maybe the problem lies somewhere else. I am trying to serve index.html on all requests which come in. I have edited the server block in my question. Is that what might be causing a problem?
ps: it does not serve the html till i have the proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; in the location / block

Comment: this should not be dependent on nginx - nginx is proxying to node, so you need to serve index.html in node. not sure about the port in the server name btw - try removing that, just `localhost` should do

Comment: Getting node to serve index.html and changing to localhost seems to work. Thanks!
But i have another question now, is it not better that nginx serves the index.html file, like i am getting it to serve all other static content? Any idea of how to get nginx to do that alongside node?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69289/discussion-between-anurag-29-and-mvuajua).